# Summarizing "percent error" for several data points

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, reporting

this is a pretty simple question, but ive never taken a stats class in my life.

i have a series of measurements, e.g., 4.5, 6.7, and 8.2, and the "correct" values, e.g., 4.6, 6.5, 8.0. I want to summarize this data in a single line of a table. Using the average + standard deviation would give a high RSD, leading the reader to think there is more error than there is. What metric should I use instead? Median + average %error or something like that?

Comment: Why not just present mean squared error or mean absolute error? So $\sum (x_i - \hat{x_i})^2$ where $x_i$ is the correct value, and $\hat{x_i}$ is the measurement? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have two sets of data. One is about ~80 samples and they all "should" be to one. My results is 1.05 +/- 0.10 (as reported in paper). I don't have the "true" value for this set of data since is labor intensive to obtain that data.

The other set is 5 samples, and the "true value" is different for each of them, and it ranges from 1.5-3.0.  Since there only 5 data points, I obtained the "correct" value of it. I didn't want to report these 5 measurements as "avg of 2.5 +/- 1.0" since that might make the reader think there is more error in those measurements than in the data set.

Comment: I am leaning towards reporting the average + standard deviation for the ~80 samples, and the range and mean squared error (i think your suggest makes sense?) for the other set. They don't have to be directly comparable, just needs to demonstrate the degree of error to the reader.